# Computing $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ for uniformly continuous functions

Tags: analysis, functions

So a function is uniformly continuous if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 $ s.t. $\forall x,y$, $|x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Is there another category of functions for which $\delta = g(\epsilon)$ for some function $g$? I.e. given an $\epsilon > 0$, we can always compute $\delta$. Or if there's not necessarily a closed form expression, maybe it is possible to give an algorithm for computing $\delta$?

Comment: The selection of $\delta$ is problem-dependent. $\delta$ is related to $\epsilon$ but is not a function of $\epsilon$ since it is not uniquely determined by a given $\epsilon$

Comment: There is always _some_ function $g$ such that $g(\epsilon)=\delta$ works.  Such a function is called a modulus of continuity for $f$.

Comment: Moreover, unless $f$ is constant, then for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$ very large values of $\delta$ will not work, so one can get a canonical function of $\epsilon$ by taking the supremum of all values of $\delta$ that work (and adjusting the $<$'s in the definition of uniform continuity to $\leq$).